# Создание статических свойств динамически (в конструкторе )

Tags: php, классы, static

Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше такое реализовать
Нужно чтоб создаваемые свойства были статическими.

```
class Config
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('config.json'), true);
        foreach($json as $k=>$v){
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя определить статические свойства класса динамически. Вы можете сформировать динамически обращение к уже существующему свойству, при помощи `self::$k` и `static::$k`. Однако, создать новое статическое свойство в объекте невозможно, собственно статическая переменная находится на уровне класса.

Я так понимаю, вы хотите создать словарь с конфигурационными настройками? Тогда лучше создать одну статическую переменную-массив и хранить данные в ней, а еще лучше реализовать интерфейс [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.arrayaccess.php) и пользоваться полученным объектом, как массивом (запретив вносить в него изменения).